# Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Config\Repository::__construct() must be of the type array, integer given

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

I'm having problem in issuing this command `php artisan cache:clear`, or `php artisan` I get this error.

> Catchable fatal error:  Argument 1 passed to
>   Illuminate\Config\Repository::__construct() must be of the type array,
>   integer given integer given, called in
>   /var/www/mysite/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/LoadConfiguration.php
>   on line 32 and defined in
>   /var/www/mysite/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Config/Repository.php
>   on line 24

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you updated your Laravel version? Manually delete `bootstrap/cache/compiled.php` and try again.

Comment: which is your php version?

Comment: @ViralSolani according to the message, it looks more recent.

Answer (score 3):

Solved in Laravel 5.5 by deleting the `config.php` file in `bootstrap/cache` folder then running `php artisan config:cache`

Answer (score 2):

**Solved**
Rename your `cache.php` file, located in `bootstrap/cache/`. 
After this, run `php artisan config:cache` command if still not working.

Answer (score 0):

In your config/***.php file, the first line must be

```
<?php
```

NOT

```
<?
```